# CodeKit with Rails app - refresh the browser without compiling anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codekit

CodeKit is great, because it refresh my browser (any) and let me view changes in real time on mobile devices connected to the same network.

But **I don't want CodeKit to compile things** (SASS, for example). Rails do all the compilation magic behind the scenes.

I just want it for the auto-refreshing browser feature.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to `.gitignore` is working for now.

```
# CodeKit stuff
config.codekit
app/assets/css/
app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache/
```